# Ansible playbook terminates if 0 active hosts despite tasks for localhost

Tags: ansible

I have a simple test playbook

```
- name: Localhost stuff - Phase 1
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:  
    - debug:
        msg: "Running Phase 1 on localhost"
         
- name: Remote tasks
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  ignore_unreachable: no
  tasks:    
    - name: Run task on remote
      shell: "ls -l"

- name: Localhost stuff - Phase 2
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Running Phase 2 on localhost"
```

I don't understand why if the hosts: all section has two hosts where 1 is reachable and 1 not reachable, then the playbook will run to completion and run the second localhost task, whereas if there is only a single host, which is unreachable, then the second localhost task does not run and the playbook terminates after the remote command.

I assume ansible thinks it has no active hosts in the second case, but ignores the fact that localhost tasks exist.

How can I change the behaviour, so it does not terminate the entire playbook, but allows the localhost tasks to run?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, *`ignore_unreachable`* was [designed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/43857) to solve also this [problem](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37309). As a result, it's up to you to handle unreachable hosts. For example, end the unreachable host(s) on your own

```yaml
- name: Play1
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ping:

- name: Play2
  hosts: host03
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: End unreachable hosts
      block:
        - ping:
          register: result
          ignore_unreachable: true
        - meta: end_host
          when: result.unreachable|default(false)
    - command: ls -l

- name: Play3
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

This playbook will proceed to the 3rd play also in case a single host will be unreachable in the 2nd play, e.g.

```yaml
PLAY [Play1] *********************************************************************************

TASK [ping] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [Play2] *********************************************************************************

TASK [ping] **********************************************************************************
fatal: [host03]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false 
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host test_19 port 22: No route to host'
  skip_reason: Host host03 is unreachable
  unreachable: true

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

PLAY [Play3] *********************************************************************************

TASK [ping] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host03                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```